# Define a nested Record type that narrows as you traverse

Tags: typescript

My system has permissions defined as a string[] like so

```
const stringVals = [
  'create:user',
  'update:user',
  'delete:user',
  'create:document',
  'update:document',
  'delete:document',
  'delete:workflow',
  'run:workflow',
] as const
```

I have the following types

```
type StringVals = typeof stringVals[number]
type PermissionVerb<T extends string> = T extends `${infer Action}:${string}` ? Action : never
type PermissionKey<T extends string, V extends PermissionVerb<T>> = T extends `${V}:${infer Key}` ? Key : never
```

which work great for things like

```
type Verbs = PermissionVerbs<StringVals> // 'create' | 'update' | 'delete' | 'run'
type CreateKeys = PermissionKey<StringVals, 'create'> // 'user' | 'document'
type RunKeys = PermissionKey<StringVals, 'run'> // 'workflow'
```

I'm hoping to create a single permission object that would look like this

```
{
  create: {
    user: true,
    document: true
  },
  update: {
    user: true,
    document: true
  },
  delete: {
    user: true,
    document: true,
    workflow: true,
  },
  run: {
    workflow: true,
  }
}
```

It's defining the right type for this object that I'm struggling with.

```
type PermissionsObject<T extends string> = Record<PermissionVerb<T>, Record<PermissionKey<T, PermissionVerb<T>>, boolean>>

function createPermissionsObject<T extends string>(permissions: Readonly<T[]>): PermissionsObject<T> {
  throw 'not implemented'
}
```

The problem with this is the first Record doesn't narrow the inner Record. So outer object key of `run`, returns everything, not just `workflow` like I want.

```
const permissions = createPermissionsObject(stringVals)
permissions.run.user // expect error
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOBLMBzAagQwDYRgXhgG0BYAKBhgHJh4BTDKWgLgFcJb5KAaMiylgA4ATBszYduvKkNpZajVu049yVGvQVCQwFgFtaYKJNX9hoplp37DxvjLmbteg0ZV3Z85gHcQ8ANYAZlggXrZU8CxgTD7+QSHGALowGLigkFBkZFAAngK0MADKUEiomDj4MDl5IAFwxcjo2BCEYHoARhwJWbn5AAocuogQEIjgaBxtADwAKjC0AB6MYEK4CA0AfBWzC0srMAAGACQA3sgBHDAAgsBQo2AAvkwna6j3+zAA-Fc3dzBMMGBaAA3DjdPIwfrwQbDO4AaVo2Rmc0WBj2LxQXBgaGRu1wkOhIzGExm602BG2KOWuCOxzQjxOZwu8Oyb0+MGZfwBwNBpDBfQGQ0JkAA8m0AFa0G5Inao1b1VBkmAAJUlviEk3xgru43gU2m60xKtA8HVmph4GZM0xZqFOr1pMxbRAIDkGDApMypACkR+4Bg6lENruEFFEqlFNxdRKKHWAAo8lCteAIP8VRgtGAsIjpoQEusAJT-IPJ0OSqAkmDHKRQAAW8BCVDAIFgiF0Ajk1kYQkoZHunrS0BgCYJwYqAcYxZF4rLsfRZQg+bIw6TkAAdBEwKvLM5DDAAPR75F5G5zeD1+BAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to use a *mapped type* so that each key `K` can be used to compute its corresponding type.

```
type PermissionsObject<T extends string> = {
  [K in PermissionVerb<T>]: 
    Extract<T, `${K}${string}`> extends `${string}:${infer Key}`
      ? Record<Key, boolean>
      : never
}
```

`K` can be used with `Extract` to get the full path from `T` where `K` is the `Action`. We can now `infer` the `Key` from this result and use it in `Record<Key, boolean>`.

```
const permissions = createPermissionsObject(stringVals)
permissions.run.workflow
permissions.create.user

permissions.run.user
//              ^^^^ Property 'user' does not exist on type 
//                   'Record<"workflow", boolean>'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=31&ssc=90&pln=26&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOBLMBzAagQwDYRgXhgG0BYAKBhgHJh4BTDKWgLgFcJb5KAaMiylgA4ATBszYduvKkNpZajVu049yVGvQVCQwFgFtaYKJNX9hoplp37DxvjLmbteg0ZV3Z85gHcQ8ANYAZlggXrZU8CxgTD7+QSHGALowGLigkFBkZFAAngK0MADKUEiomDj4MDl5IAFwxcjo2BCEYHoARhwJWbn5AAocuogQEIjgaBxtADwAKjC0AB6MYEK4CA0AfBWzC0srMAAGACQA3sgBHDAAgsBQo2AAvkwna6j3+zAA-Fc3dzBMMGBaAA3DjdPIwfrwQbDO4AaVo2Rmc0WBj2LxQXBgaGRu1wkOhIzGExm602BG2KOWuCOxzQjxOZwu8Oyb0+MGZfwBwNBpDBfQGQ0JkAA8m0AFa0G5Inao1b1VBkmDHKSEWEwZAQgUwonwKbTdYJf4AUUW8AwUummJpsPuz3lKDemxlVIOdpKDqepzA53g7IRbykFC+ACVJb4hJNmZi2iAQHIMGB1oHOYCQfAyPdMqQApEfuAYOpRPjBXcIKKJRacbK6u71gAKPJQkvgCD-UMYLRgLCI6aEBLrACU-2L2pF4slUBJSqkUAAFvAQlQwCBYIhdAI5NZGEJKBms2loDBGwTSxVC4wR0Ky+ObnX0WUIAOyMfm5AAHQRMBvmKBYJeZ9aleb7nrQb7iOmvKkC+o4QB+kRgUoZAAPRIRQaHoRhAB62GYRCC6NjkVDgZQMBaLQuDLrACxDLA+ZVPklChqA8ARgARD+cReKx0axvGiaUEAA)

---

Bonus:

A few characters shorter but same result.

```
type PermissionsObject<T extends string> = {
  [K in T as PermissionVerb<K>]: 
    [K] extends [`${string}:${infer Key}`]
      ? Record<Key, boolean>
      : never
}
```